My screen behaves weird in Ubuntu today
Look at the very right side of the screen in the image provided

I looked very hard, but I do not see weird behavior in the graphic. I see a custom themed desktop, however, so any issue may be in the custom theme.

There is nothing wrong with the picture. Are you trying to get people to subscribe to that channel?

Maybe the display has some problems. The screenshot looks normal. Can you take a photo from your phone?
